# Code similar to Mastermind

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm attempting to create a simple code similar to the game mastermind but with a 5 digit password such as (0 2 5 3 9). Able  to generate the password but lost about how to use the user input to compare with the password. Any hints, this is what I have.

```
import random   
def masterkey():
     code = []
     i = 0
     while i < 5:
          digit = random.randint(0,9)
          code.append(digit)
          i=i+1
     print code
     counter = 0
     while counter < 10:
          counter += 1
          guess = raw_input("Guess my five digit password: ")
          if guess == code:
               print "Congrats, you're lucky!"
          else:
           .....
```

I know this isn't correct but totally lost on this part of the code.

Thanks.

Comment: `guess` is a string and `code` is an array. You may want to compare: `guess == "".join(code)`. Second, your question is not clear, you're at lost about what exactly ?

Comment: sorry I'm fairly new to coding, I'm lost in the sense of what operations and such I can use to compare the user input to the computer's code. I know there are functions such as .find() but unsure about how to go about using those and also whether the computer string is acceptable just like that.

Answer (score 2):

We won't just write the code for you, but here are some pointers that should send you in the right direction:

- Write down, in the simplest, most non-ambiguous way, what *exactly* you need to compare. For example, **"Count the number of digits in the user's input that exist in the password"** and **"Count the number of input digits that are in the same place as the password"**
- Research how to do each of those steps independently.
- Implement those solutions in your code, one after another.

If you're still stuck, come back here and ask a specific question about where you're stuck. (How you're getting a different result than expected, or what error you receive)

We'll be waiting :)

Comment: Understand that I should learn on my own, I've converted the users input into a list but now this is where I'm not even sure how to compare. How would I go about comparing each individual element?

Comment: Once you've boiled down the problem to a small issue, and tried to code it, you can ask a new, much more direct question; i.e. "I'm trying to count matches in this list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] against this string: '32513' but it says there aren't any. Here's my code: `sum(i in secret for i in answer)`". You'll get a bunch of responses in just a couple minutes. Be sure to try and search for duplicates of these small questions, because they doubtlessly exist.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really very nice to use all those `while` loops. `for` loops not only save you code, but make it harder to introduce off by one bugs. Save the `while` loops for when you really need them

```
import random   
def masterkey():
    code = [random.randint(0,9) for i in range(5)]
    for counter in range(10):
        guess = raw_input("Guess my five digit password: ")
        # guess is string, so need to convert it to a list of ints
        guess = [int(c) for c in guess]
        ...
```

Alternatively, you can leave guess as a string by making the initial code a string in the first place. THis is a little more robust, as the user can't crash your program just by entering non digits.

```
import random   
def masterkey():
    code = "".join(random.choice("0123456789") for i in range(5))
    for counter in range(10):
        guess = raw_input("Guess my five digit password: ")
        ...
```

Finally a tip:

If you think guess should be equal to code:

```
      if guess == code:
           print "Congrats, you're lucky!"
      else:
           print repr(guess), "!=", repr(code)
```

will quickly show you why not